# What are the different enchantments for the Octopus King Crown

Tags: candy-box-2

I beat the Octo-King and took his crown.  Now I am at the wishing well and I can enchant it with jaspers or obsidian.  What are the perks of each?  Can I get a second crown and enchant it with the other option?

[image: Options]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Jasper crown shoots fireballs at random.  It's a great way to beat the Monkey Wizard.

The Obsidian Crown randomly summons octopuses to fight for you.

You can get a second Octopus Crown once you enchant the first (And you can get a third after enchanting the second).

Comment: What are the odds of the Obsidian spawning minions?

Comment: @Batophobia I have been looking for any information that even hints at what it is, but so far nothing.  I'll update the answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR obsidian spawns octopuses (can be very annoying, they may block you), jaspers spawn fireballs.

Answer (score 1):

with jaspers it shoots big fireballs like red gloves
with obsidian summons octopuses which blocks you